# What is the online survey/feedback widget that looks like "[+]" (a crosshair) in the bottom right

Tags: tools, online

I'm trying to setup a site rating survey so marketing in my company can gather feedback information about a site. I've seen before large companies using a tool which puts a small animated crosshair in the bottom right of the screen [+]. what on earth is this company called? multiple searches don't seem to bring it up!

Comment: I know what you mean, I've seen it myself. However I can't remember which sites I've seen it on. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

A company that provides this service is: [OpinionLab](http://opinionlab.com)

And an example of this in action is here on [Dell's site](http://www.dell.co.uk/): look at the bottom of the page just above the country specific web sites.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the question...

Comment: You are right and I have edited my "answer" to become an answer ;-)

Comment: Look down. Now look back up. Your downvote is now an upvote! (you should remove the old content from your answer now)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the one with a [+], but a [Feedback] button - http://getsatisfaction.com/

http://www.crunchbase.com/company/satisfaction shows their competitors as 
http://uservoice.com/, http://www.feedbackify.com/, and others.