# Fixed Mini Feedback Form Widget on the Bottom Corner of a Web Page

Tags: tools, widgets, contact-page

On some websites, there are fixed mini contact forms on the bottom corner of a web page. An example website is [Olark](http://www.olark.com/).

I couldn't find out the name of this kind of form apps.

Does anybody know what they are called and is there any ready made component or tutorial how to implement them?

[image: Contact form minimized on the corner]

[image: Contact form expanded]

Note:
There is a similar widget question here as well:
[What is the online survey/feedback widget that looks like "[+]" (a crosshair) in the bottom right](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/what-is-the-online-survey-feedback-widget-that-looks-like-a-crosshair-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply DOM manipulation using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - more often than not using a JavaScript library like [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or similar.

The HTML containing the form (or whatever content) is hidden until the action element is clicked revealing the hidden content (either immediately or with a transition).

Some examples can be found here:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Contactable-IzzyHelp
- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tab-slide-out